# Typescript not compiling what was working before

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

I made some bugfixes on the backend of my webapp (node, docker) and when AWS tries to upload the new version it was giving Javascript heap out of memory error. After several tries, it seemed to be the tsc command failing.

Looking online found this: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/53397 where i needed to import a specific version of "express-serve-static-core". After doing that, the error changed and now its throwing me 121 different errors like

> src/types/definitions/birth-view.d.ts:6:18 - error TS2320: Interface 'BirthView' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Document<any, any, any>' and 'IBirthView'.
> Named property '_id' of types 'Document<any, any, any>' and 'IBirthView' are not identical.

> src/repositories/mongoose/mongoose.repository.ts:56:18 - error TS2707: Generic type 'Query<ResultType, DocType, THelpers, RawDocType>' requires between 2 and 4 type arguments.
>
> 56  populate(query: Query, fieldsToPopulate: string[] | QueryPopulateOptions[]): Query {

I have always been using "typescript": "^3.9.10", but I've tried playing with typescript versions to no avail. What blows my mind is why it was working fine before, and suddenly it shows 121 errors even in files that have not been changed in a long time and were working fine.

How was my code working before when interface 'birthview' could simultaneously extend 2 types that have not been changed and now it cant?

Im at the brink of going insane, thanks in advance.

I have tried playing with typescript and express-serve-static-core versions but can't make it work like it was doing before.